# Best way to put environment file in a Laravel Container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, gitlab, amazon-ecs

Starting from the base image `php:7.4-apache`, I'm containerizing a **Laravel application** that will be served on **AWS ECS Fargate**, but I'm struggling to understand the proper way to include the `.env` file.

As soon as the code is pushed on the master branch, a **GitLab** runner builds the container and pushes it on **ECR**.

Currently in the Dockerfile I:

- Install the required packages and PHP extensions
- Enable required PECL
- Copy and configure the Apache Virtual Host
- Edit the `php.ini` starting from the `$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production`
- Download and run `composer`

I don't understand what's the best way to include the .env file in the container filesystem.

I ended up downloading the `.env` from AWS **Secrets Manager** in the GitLab runner during the build; it basically puts it in the Laravel folder, then completes the build and pushes it in ECR, but it means having all the credentials in the container registry.

What's the right way to address this?
What's the best practice to download and include the .env file in a Laravel Docker Container?

Comment: Have your Fargate container do the same thing the Gitlab runner does; pull the .env from AWS Secrets Manager on startup.

Comment: @ceejayoz I can do it with a shell script in a CMD, right? Alternatives?

Comment: @GiacomoTorricelli this is configured in the AWS ECS Task Definition. It will automatically set the environment variables when (before) the container starts. You _could_ also do this as part of your container's `ENTRYPOINT` script, but you will probably need the AWS SDK or CLI installed in the container. Defining the secrets source in the Task Definition is probably the easier of the two options.